# How and where do I execute a function after the user closes an app?

Tags: swift

Can I include a function that runs once if the user closes the app? If so, where should I put that function because I don't know which view controller the user will be closing the app from. What's the solution?

Comment: Application delegate.

Comment: What do you mean here by "close the app?" Do you mean "press the home button to suspend?" Or "swipe up on the app list to kill?" Or something else? What kind of operation do you want to run (how long it might take and whether it is asynchronous dramatically changes how to do this).

Comment: No, not home button. After clicking home the app still running just in background. I mean "swipe up on the app list to kill". I need to send some data to server when the user closes the app.

Answer (score 5):

In `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Comment: I understand that applicationWillTerminate will NOT called when the user kills the app from app list. So what function should I use? ApplicationDidEnterBackground also isn't appropriate for my needs because it called when the app is in background.

Comment: Everything to do with starting, stopping, foreground, background, etc. is in  `AppDelegate.swift`. You should see a bunch of "stub" methods that have comments in them.